# Sum vertically until empty cell on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-docs

This is the scenario. I need to get the sum of the values until it reaches a blank cell. After that it should start again calculating the sum after the blank cell. I need to add the fat and carbs of every ingredient of each dish individually. 
[image]

This is the expected result. That for each of hundreds of dishes. In this case I entered the data manually:

[image]

I tried with this but is adding all of the data from the column:

```
IF(SUM(C3:C)="","",SUM(C3:C)))
```

I also tried with this formula but is not working:

```
IF(C3:C="","",SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(C3:C),COLUMN(C3:C400))&":"&"C"&MIN(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C3:C400="",ROW(C3:C400),""))))))
```

[This is the spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IcnSbnWcU59_o1bGWdtBOldg7px34lc631HgZ0K4xRQ/edit?usp=sharing) in case you need it.

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would just make a small adjustment to your formula:

```
IF(C2="",SUM(C3:INDEX(C3:C,MATCH(TRUE,(C3:C=""),0))),"")
```

so the first total is 11 instead of 9.

[image]

This is an (experimental) array-formula version based on numbering each group using the presence of a Dish in the first row of each group as a marker:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A2:A="","",vlookup(countifs(A2:A,"<>",row(A2:A),"<="&row(A2:A)),
query({C2:C,countifs(A2:A,"<>",row(A2:A),"<="&row(A2:A))},"select Col2,sum(Col1) group by Col2"),2)))
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have any approaches to achieving this with ArrayFormula?

Comment: I'm thinking if you numbered each group (maybe using countifs) you could do a 'group by' query to find the sum for each group? Will need to experiment with it.

Comment: This is what I had in mind: =ArrayFormula(if(A2:A="","",vlookup(countifs(A2:A,"<>",row(A2:A),"<="&row(A2:A)),
query({C2:C,countifs(A2:A,"<>",row(A2:A),"<="&row(A2:A))},"select Col2,sum(Col1) group by Col2"),2)))

Comment: Excellent, thanks.  I will start with this and let you know how it goes!